# BigQuery: Running query against large dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have approximately 100TB of data that I need to backfill by running query against to transform fields, then write the transformation to another table. This table is partitioned by ingestion time timestamp. I have both action as a part of single query as you can see below. I am planning to run this query multiple times in smaller chunks manually by ingestion timestamp ranges.

Is there a better way handle this process rather than running query in manual chunks? For example maybe using Dataflow or other framework.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.table
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) AS
with load as (SELECT *, _TABLE_SUFFIX as tableId
    FROM `project.dataset.table_*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1' AND '1531835999999'
    ),................
     ...................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accurately dose the queries you run as there are very limiting quote enforcement.

**Partitioned tables**

- Maximum number of partitions per partitioned table — 4,000
- Maximum number of partitions modified by a single job — 2,000
- Each job operation (query or load) can affect a maximum of 2,000 partitions. Any query or load job that affects more than 2,000 partitions is rejected by Google BigQuery.
- Maximum number of partition modifications per day per table — 5,000
  You are limited to a total of 5,000 partition modifications per day for a partitioned table. A partition can be modified by using an operation that appends to or overwrites data in the partition. Operations that modify partitions include: a load job, a query that writes results to a partition, or a DML statement (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE) that modifies data in a partition.
- More than one partition may be affected by a single job. For example, a DML statement can update data in multiple partitions (for both ingestion-time and partitioned tables). Query jobs and load jobs can also write to multiple partitions but only for partitioned tables. Google BigQuery uses the number of partitions affected by a job when determining how much of the quota the job consumes. Streaming inserts do not affect this quota.
- Maximum rate of partition operations — 50 partition operations every 10 seconds

Most of the time you hit the second limitation, single job no more than 2000, and if you parallelise further you hit the last one, 50 partition operations every 10 seconds.

On the other hand the [DML MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) syntax could come into your help.

If you have a sales representative reach out to the BQ team and if they can increase some of your quotas they will respond positive.

Also I've seen people using multiple projects to run jobs past of the quotas.

Comment: I am aware of the timeout limits. My question was more along how to do this better than how I am doing.

Comment: What timeout limits? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean quota limits for partitions. My question is more on what is the best practice for backfilling large dataset which inserts to  multiple partitions. Currently I am having to manually run query multiple times. It would be nice to be able to parallelize and automate this operation.

Comment: You need to build out the automation and scripting of these using one of your favorite programming languages and scheduled things either using cron jobs, or message queues whatever you've done in past to run async scheduled/throttled things.